# Refresh Scatter Plot in Iphone Core Plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I have search this question but didnt find any answer that help me. i have tried [graph reloadData] but didnt help me. 
I m using this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) to make Scatter plot graph for my project

But i m making just 1 scatter graph not 3.
i have 3 options in settings 1)today 2)month 3)year
in today it shows todays graph just 1 plot
in month it shows 30 plot and 365 in year.
but in my case it works ony first time but when i go back and change option from today to year it.

Comment: When i click today and it draws this http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2012-11-08_at_2.39.38_PM-IEiHkPI7.png

when i go back and click year it draws like this http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2012-11-08_at_2.40.21_PM-40BMoO48.png

and when i restart app and click year it draws this http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2012-11-08_at_2.45.03_PM-YPvWdupx.png

and when i select today than app crashed says index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: please edit your question and post the additional info/clarification there (instead of in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone. it wasnt about refreshing graph. i had an array of dates and it was static. so it changes once when the date was selected like today or month. and then when i select option again that static array had the previous values not new.